# How to break out of an iFrame with Zope's/Plone's REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect call?

Tags: iframe, plone, zope

I got a form within an iFrame.
When the form is submitted, it gets properly processed, and I want to redirect to a page - outside of the iFrame.

For the redirection I use `REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect(response_url)` but then the content always is rendered inside the iFrame.

The redirect method does not offer any option here:

```
    def redirect(self, location, status=302, lock=0):
    """Cause a redirection without raising an error"""
    self.setStatus(status, lock=lock)
    self.setHeader('Location', location)

    return str(location)
```

Is there any Zope/Plone trick what to do?

I'd prefer to avoid building some JavaScript function which tests how deeply nested the frames are.

Comment: You can’t do that with an HTTP redirect - HTTP has no concept of such arbitrary human constructs as “browser windows” or “frames”. Either put a `target` attribute on the form to begin with, or - use client-side JavaScript to break out of the frame _after_ the result of the form submission has been loaded into the frame first.

Comment: For best results, please post Plone questions on our forum at https://community.plone.org